# use custom field value as post category in loop

Tags: custom-field, loop, codex

I have a page template and at the bottom, I want a loop of posts based on a custom field value - store_name

This is what I have:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => '10','paged'=>$paged,'category_name'=>'<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'store_name', true); ?>'));
                ?>
```

But of course that doesn't work because I know my syntax is incorrect with the nested php statement, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.

Got it working with:

```
<?php
                    global $wp_query;

                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

                    $store_name = (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'store_name', true));

                    query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => '10','paged'=>$paged,'category_name'=>$store_name));
                ?>
```